# Wordpress MySQL query post type

Tags: sql, wordpress

I want to add post_type option to this query. How can I do it?

`$state = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT meta_value AS state, COUNT(post_id) AS count
    FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key = 'personal_nation'
    GROUP BY state ORDER BY state DESC");`

Comment: Add how? Add to result, or filter by it in the where clause? Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text. Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT meta_value AS state, COUNT(post_id) AS count, post_id 
FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'personal_nation' 
AND post_id in(select ID from wp_posts where post_type="post") 
GROUP BY state ORDER BY state DESC
```

Comment: It works for me. Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: glad to help you